# ReactJS loading images from filesystem outside project

Tags: html, image, reactjs, filesystems

I have an application where I store in database the image paths. The paths are relative to my file system, not to the project.

When I issue in React:

```
<img alt={this.props.alt} src={require('/fs/storage/images/logo.jpg')}/>
```

I´m getting the following error:

```
You attempted to import /fs/storage/images/logo.jpg which falls outside of the project
src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. 
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules.
```

How can I solve that ? Where should I put the symlink that the message is suggesting ?

Comment: *JavaScript which runs on Client Browser* doesn't have access to the file system.

Answer (score 0):

How you can read filesystem or db from react if it on client side?
Do you have server? That communicate with database?

You should read image on server and send in on client, where use it in React